# Error with "this" in IE with jQuery plugin

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-plugins

I'm coding a plugin for jQuery which now works fine on every browser but IE. This is part of the code:

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {

        var methods = {
            getFirstList: function(el){
                return $("ul:first", el);
            }
        };

        return this.each(function(){
            ...
            var list = methods.getFirstList(this); 
            // "this" here refers to window or document in IE.
            ...
        });
    };
})( jQuery );
```

When I call the plugin (`$("#myObject").myPlugin();`), the keyword "this" is not refered to the DOM object, but to the window or document.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that is the exact code that demonstrates this problem?

Comment: I've just added a few more lines of code to make it clearer.

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `this` with `$(this)`

Comment: Aye, return this.each(function(){ should be return $(this).each(function(){; .each is not a function of the DOMs this object.

Comment: @RussC: In a plugin, the main `this` is already a jQuery object.

Comment: Good point, I glazed over that bit, however  the 'this' inside getFirstList isn't necessarily a jQuery object is it ?

Comment: @RussC: Nope, but it doesn't need to be either (in the current context).

Comment: I guess we need Gerado to state what his exact error message is, yes it's a truism, but if it's not either of the two lines I stated, then it's not his snippet.